# assign array value to element using loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How can I give `li` the value of a,b,c? currently with my below code I got all c.

```
arr = ['a','b','c'];

arr.forEach(function(obj){
var x = obj;
    $('li').each(function () {
        $(this).text(x);
    });

});
```

Something is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3):

That is because you are iterating over all `li` when iterating over array and setting the value.  jquery `.text()` accepts function as argument which accepts index as parameter. This will eliminates the need of iterating over li and array elements:

```
var arr = ['a','b','c'];    
$('li').text(function(i){
  return arr[i];
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dt73Lrzs/)**

Answer (score 3):

First, you set the text of all `li` to `'a'`, then to `'b'` and finally to `'c'`.

Instead, you may try iterating the `li` elements, and set the text content of the current one to the corresponding item in `arr`:

```
var arr = ['a','b','c'];
$('li').each(function(i) {
    $(this).text(arr[i]);
});
```

```js
var arr = ['a','b','c'];
$('li').each(function(i) {
    $(this).text(arr[i]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Alternatively (but similarly), you can iterate the array, and set the text content of the corresponding `li` to the current value:

```
var arr = ['a','b','c'],
    $li = $('li');
arr.forEach(function(txt, i) {
  $li.eq(i).text(txt);
});
```

```js
var arr = ['a','b','c'],
    $li = $('li');
arr.forEach(function(txt, i) {
  $li.eq(i).text(txt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should iterate by `arr`, not by all `li` elements, you can do it like this:

```
arr = ['a','b','c'];
$.each(arr, function(i,v){
    $('li').eq(i).text(v);
});
```

This way you will assign exactly the same number of `li` text as there is elements in the array.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, everytime the outer iterator performed, all `<li>` was texted with the iteration result. So as a result you'll get all 'c'.

To do it right, you should code like this:

```
arr = ['a','b','c'];
$('li').each(function(index) {
    $(this).text(arr[index]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery `each()` function will pass in an index, which you can use

```
arr = ['a','b','c'];

$('li').each(function(i) {
    $(this).text(arr[i]);
});
```